# Postgres: How to join tables when every table can be empty?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables. And I use math operations for this three tables.

```
SELECT table_1.a + table_2.a + table_3.a
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.user_id = table_1.user_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_3.user_id = table_1.user_id
WHERE table_1.user_id = ?
```

But every table from this query can be empty.

How I can fix to work correctly with empty tables?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a `full join`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Since any of the tables can be empty, the conditions will get lengthy both for the `ON` as well as the `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1.a T1
LEFT JOIN table_2 T2 ON T1.user_Id = T2.FK
```

FK is your foreign key on the second table. A Left Join will return all rows from table1 even if they don't exist in table2.

Comment: I understood that any of the tables could have no row for `user_id`. The question did not mention th foreign key relationship that you are assuming.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way  would be to `LEFT JOIN` against a row that contains your target id.
Then (if so desired) use `coalesce()` to replace the null values and get a non null result where rows are missing.

```
WITH target AS (SELECT ? AS user_id)
SELECT coalesce(table_1.a,0) 
       + coalesce(table_2.a,0) 
       + coalesce(table_3.a,0) AS sum_a
FROM target
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON target.user_id = table_1.user_id
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON target.user_id = table_2.user_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON target.user_id = table_3.user_id
;
```

You could as well start with `users_table.user_id` or some such where `user_id` is the primary key and you know the user_id must exist (You probably have FK relationships here?). And filter using a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT coalesce(table_1.a,0) 
       + coalesce(table_2.a,0) 
       + coalesce(table_3.a,0) AS sum_a
FROM user_table u
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON u.user_id = table_1.user_id
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON u.user_id = table_2.user_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON u.user_id = table_3.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = ?
;
```